# "takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given"

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm  creating a twitter-bot which should create tweets with random words. Therefore I created two Arrays with strings to put them inside of the tweet. Inside of `client.create_tweet` I tried to use the `random.choice` function, but it doesn't work. It appears an error:

```
Client.create_tweet() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given.
```

```
from email.utils import localtime
import tweepy 
import time
import random

name = ["x", "y", "z"]
adjektiv = ["a", "b", "c"]




class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient): 
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet.text)

        client.retweet(tweet.id)

        client.like(tweet.id)

        client.create_tweet(tweet.id, text = random.choice(name) + " is "+          random.choice(adjektiv))
       
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You can't choose a tweet ID for a new tweet; Twitter generates that.

Comment: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet

Comment: The "1 positional argument" it expects is the implicit argument `client`; you are providing the client *and* the unexpected ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`create_tweet`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet) doesn't have a `tweet_id` argument. Remove it and you should be OK:

```py
client.create_tweet(text = random.choice(name) + " is " + random.choice(adjektiv))
```